# pcl_ros build error in Fuerte on Fedora 17 x64

Tags: ros, pcl, ros-fuerte, perception-pcl, fedora

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Followed the [instructions](http://www.ros.org/wiki/fuerte/Installation/Fedora) for Fuerte installation on Fedora, but stuck on pcl_ros compilation with errors similar to:

```
/opt/ros/fuerte/include/message_filters/sync_policies/approximate_time.h:620:119: error: ‘value’ is not a member of ‘ros::message_traits::TimeStamp’
```

Looks like incompatibility between ROS core libraries and pcl_ros. Where I am wrong?

Versions:

- Fedora 17 x86_64 RFRemix
- pcl.x86_64 1.5.1-2.fc17 (installed by yum)
- perception_pcl 1.2.3 (pulled by rosinstall)

Full log is [here](http://pastebin.com/RrwhRRz7) (see lines 12, 13, 23 for errors)

---

EDIT: Tried several versions from [wg-deps](https://github.com/wg-debs/pcl-release) with no result.

The package is configured as:

```
cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" -DUSE_ROS=ON -DBUILD_TESTS=OFF -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release
```

Still it gives same 3 errors during pcl_ros compilation.

Although I found a temporary solution - convert Ubuntu DEB package with [alien](http://joeyh.name/code/alien/) to RPM - I am still interested in building native package. Probably need some black magic.

---

EDIT #2: It all the same.

There is a strange thing in PCL sources, in `common/CMakeLists.txt` to handle ROS build there is a code which excludes PointIndicies.h header from build:

```
if(NOT USE_ROS)
    set(incs ${incs}
      include/pcl/ModelCoefficients.h
      include/pcl/PolygonMesh.h
      include/pcl/Vertices.h
      include/pcl/PointIndices.h
      include/pcl/TextureMesh.h
      )

    set(sensor_msg_incs 
      include/sensor_msgs/PointField.h
      include/sensor_msgs/PointCloud2.h
      include/sensor_msgs/Image.h
      )

    set(std_msg_incs include/std_msgs/Header.h)
endif(NOT USE_ROS)
```

However this header is then used in `common/include/pcl_base.h` and there is nothing in it to handle such situation.

At the same time PCL builds without any problems, but `pcl_ros` is complaining for a missed header `PointIndicies.h`

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/43129/pcl_ros-build-error-in-fuerte-on-fedora-17-x64/) by [Boris](https://answers.ros.org/users/2873/boris/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3060 on 2012-09-05

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like you used the stand-alone PCL 1.5.1 install package.

The pcl_ros package requires a special PCL build, containing some different header definitions and messages not included in the stand-alone version.

EDIT: it *should* depend on stand-alone PCL, but it does not. See [PCL issue 669](http://dev.pointclouds.org/issues/699) for details.

I *believe* the `ros-fuerte-pcl` Debian package is built from [this repository](https://github.com/wg-debs/pcl-release).

EDIT #2: glad `alien` was useful.

I agree that building yourself would be better. Probably, it looks similar to a [normal stand-alone PCL build](http://www.pointclouds.org/downloads/source.html), but with the USE_ROS parameter set. This is my guess (not tested):

```
$ mkdir build
$ cd build
$ cmake .. -DUSE_ROS=1
$ make 
$ sudo make install
```

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2012-09-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Boris](https://answers.ros.org/users/2873/boris/) on 2012-09-05**:
But isn't it that pcl in Fuerte *should be* standalone as mentioned in Ch.4 (Migration) http://www.ros.org/wiki/fuerte ? Also the link from http://www.ros.org/wiki/pcl to svn is broken, though I found some version of perception_pcl for fuerte, still there is no pcl inside and it gives same errors